# Getting error on extending in Custom Module vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking/view.phtml file in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, shipping, shipment-tracking

On extending the file

```
vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking/view.phtml
```

File in Magento 2.4 getting error like

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in var/www/html/hl/app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking/view.phtml on line 30
```

My file path is
app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking/view.phtml

I have checked that the file is override but it does not take the block data from there.

Any one have idea regarding that how to get those data in custom module file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share code of overriding phtml

Comment: @Pawan thanks for your response i have found the issue and solved it.

Comment: glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't extend these two files also

```
adminhtml_order_shipment_addtrack.xml and adminhtml_order_shipment_removetrack.xml
```

I have extended only adminhtml_order_shipment_view.xml this file which cause the issue then i have extend the block file as i want some modification and its working fine now.